# Maximize quadratic function over unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, qcqp

In lecture, we proved that, given a symmetric matrix $A$, the

$$\max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} x^T A x$$

is the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max}$ of matrix $A$: we diagonalize the matrix $A$ and show that for every unit vector x the inequality $x^T A x \leq \lambda_{\max}$ holds. I understand every part of the computation.

What I do not understand is why it suffices to consider unit vectors for $x$? If the inequality is true for every $x$ in the unit sphere and we find one for which the inequality is an equality, then of course we have found a maximum. But in the unit sphere do not only lie the unit vectors.

Comment: Probably Rayleigh quotient can also enlighten you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient

Comment: I think you mean *unit ball*.

Comment: No, I do not. The unit ball would be $||x||_2 \leq 1$, but we considered the sphere, i.e. $||x||_2=1$.

Comment: That is exactly where my misunderstanding did lie. I thought unit vectors are vectors of the form $e_i$, where $e_i$ has everywhere the entry $0$ except on the position i where it has the entry $1$. But that is not true.

Comment: The $e_i$ are the vectors of the standard (or canonical) basis. All vectors on the unit sphere are unit vectors to me.

Comment: Note that the inequality is $$x^T A x \leq \lambda_{\max} (A) \, \| x \|_2^2$$

Comment: Exactly, and since $||x||_2^2=1$ we obtain that $x^TAx\leq \lambda_{max}(A)$ and hence, the statement.

Comment: You can also solve $$\max_{x \neq 0}  \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider a Lagrangian function of the following form
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\vec{x},\lambda) = -\vec{x}^{\intercal}A\vec{x} + \lambda(\vec{x}^2 - 1).
\end{equation}
The first derivatives of the Lagrange function are
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\vec{x}} = -2A\vec{x} + 2\lambda\vec{x} = 0,\\
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\lambda} = \vec{x}^2 - 1 = 0.
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
A\vec{x} = \lambda\vec{x},\\
\vec{x}^2 = 1.
\end{equation}
It is seen from the last equation that the Lagrangian multiplier is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$. At a stationary point, the Lagrange function can be rewritten as follows
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = -\lambda\vec{x}^2,\\
\vec{x}^2 = 1.
\end{equation}
The last equation shows that the Lagrange function has the minimum value at $\lambda = \lambda_{\rm max}$. The min value of this function is equal to $-\lambda_{\rm max}$ only if $\vec{x}^2 = 1$. So the max value of the $\vec{x}^{\intercal}A\vec{x}$ is equal to $\lambda_{\rm max}$ only if $\vec{x}^2=1$. For $\vec{x}^2\neq1$, the value of the $\vec{x}^{\intercal}A\vec{x}$ at the maximum will be different.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. If I understand correctly, you gave an alternative prove (which is by the way much clearer to me).

Comment: It should be the minmax of this function gives us the constrained maximum of the $x^T A x$, right?
Min w.r.t $\lambda$ and Max w.r.t $x$,

Comment: You never take minimume over both variable $x$ and $\lambda$! That's very wrong!

Comment: Redshoes You're right. I was wrong. Nevertheless, the solution algorithm is correct. It is correct to say that I am looking not for a minimum, but for stationary points depending on the coordinates and the Lagrange multiplier. One of these points will meet the conditional minimum.